# EventTrigger not firing for Loaded event of UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a UserControl with the following event trigger:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Views.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         >

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

It is being set via the constructor of the UserControl (please ignore the ServiceLocator ..this is just a quick prototype):

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DirectorySearchViewModel>();
}
```

In my view-model I have the following:

```
    public ICommand OnLoadedCommand { get; private set; }

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        OnLoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnLoaded);
    }

    public void OnLoaded()
    {
    }
```

OnLoaded never gets called. If I change the EventName to say ..MouseDown, then it works but it just won't work for Loaded

Pretty sure it's a stupid mistake (swear I've done this a million times before in the past) but can't seem to figure it out right now

Comment: WAG here, but try setting your DC prior to calling InitializeComponent in the constructor.

Comment: BINGO.
ARGH! How many times do I keep making that same stupid mistake!

Please respond as an answer so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    DataContext = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<DirectorySearchViewModel>();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The Aristocrats.

Comment: This worked! Can you tell why this happens? Why does DataContext need to be set first?

Comment: @AbdulkarimKanaan Because the Loaded event fires during the call to InitializeComponent.  InitializeComponent *initializes the window*.  Once it is initialized, the Loaded event fires.  Because you set the DataContext *after* the Loaded event fires, the event trigger has nothing to trigger, and doesn't remember that the event had already fired and doesn't know you want it to trigger once the DataContext is set.  That's not how it's designed.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that stumbles across this you can do it without code behind like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Views.MyUserControl"
    ... etc...
     x:Name="theControl"
     >

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding ElementName=theControl, Path=OnLoadedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: I get this at runtime: "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ViewLoadedCommand' property not found on 'object' ''FooView' (Name='self')'. BindingExpression:Path=ViewLoadedCommand; DataItem='FooView' (Name='self'); target element is 'InvokeCommandAction' (HashCode=21993383); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')". It's looking at the view rather than the ViewModel for the command property.

Comment: Ah, it seems the solution is to use `Command="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=DataContext.ViewLoadedCommand}"` - so adding "`DataContext.`" to the `Path` works.

Comment: Oops...I don't even remember answering this question but you're absolutely correct, with these types of bindings you have to specify DataContext in the path. I must have been using the control as it's own DataContext during my own testing. Thanks for correcting my answer.

Comment: This doesn't solve the poblem if (as the OP stated) the DataContext is not yet set in the Loaded event. This is basically exactly the same as the code shown in the question.